# Interpolar en una matriz en Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolacion

estoy empezando con Python y la librería Pandas y no encuentro la manera de resolver el siguiente problema:
Tengo una matriz de rendimiento que consiste en una tabla donde los nombres de columnas son las elevaciones del sol de 3 en 3 y los índices de la tabla son los azimuts posibles del sol de 4 en 4. Cada combinación de la tabla de azimut y elevación nos da un valor de rendimiento de 0 a 1. La tengo creada como un CSV que cargo sin problema con pd.read_csv('matriz.csv')

Anteriormente el problema lo tenía resuelto en Java y al portar a Python me surge la duda de si hay una manera rápida de a partir de una entrada de azimut y elevación cualquiera me interpole el valor de rendimiento para esa combinación (ej. interpola (azi=3, ele=5)

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El módulo `scipy.interpolate` te da la solución que necesitas, si no he entendido mal la pregunta.

Entiendo que tienes una matriz como esta en un dataframe `df` (en este caso he generado los números de rendimiento entre 0 y 1 al azar):

```
           0         3         6   ...      81        84        87        90
0    0.563970  0.223814  0.830243  ... .268073  0.265994  0.649385  0.181062
4    0.241971  0.040599  0.704207  ... .262125  0.877853  0.249934  0.068609
8    0.487952  0.831713  0.643798  ... .649279  0.447494  0.152850  0.465670
12   0.709701  0.766293  0.611798  ... .844602  0.965854  0.235549  0.400060
16   0.028869  0.326765  0.545589  ... .556665  0.599250  0.103927  0.226221
..        ...       ...       ...  ...     ...       ...       ...       ...
344  0.898557  0.160302  0.054962  ... .563178  0.296605  0.948198  0.334790
348  0.919588  0.529642  0.583805  ... .672556  0.304232  0.612983  0.666282
352  0.313359  0.978925  0.313910  ... .402724  0.269286  0.314577  0.481069
356  0.015531  0.374324  0.719602  ... .253944  0.326685  0.692314  0.389440
360  0.433817  0.937384  0.817580  ... .222289  0.627653  0.817933  0.690382
```

y que buscas una función `f()` que reciba dos parámetros (elevación y azimut) de modo que si llamas `f(0,0)` te devolvería 0.563970, pues ese dato está en la tabla (y análogamente `f(3,0)` devolvería 0.223814 y así con todos los datos que estén en la tabla), pero que si pides un dato que no está en la tabla, como `f(1,1)` te devuelva el valor que resultaría interpolando los datos que sí están en la tabla.

Pues la clase `scipy.interpolate.interp2d()` hace exactamente lo que buscas. No forma parte de pandas, por lo que hay que extraer adecuadamente del dataframe los datos para pasárselos a esta clase.

El siguiente código muestra cómo hacerlo:

```
from scipy import interpolate
f = interpolate.interp2d(df.columns, df.index, df.values, kind='linear')

print(f(0,0)) # Estos tres primeros son para comprobar
print(f(3,0)) # pues son datos que ya estaban
print(f(3,4)) # en la tabla
print(f(1,1)) # Este ya es un dato interpolado
```

Esto produciría el resultado:

```
[0.56397036]
[0.22381431]
[0.04059928]
[0.38165045]
```

**Notas**.

- La función `f` espera como primer parámetro la elevación y como segundo parámetro el azimut
- Lo que retorna `f` es un array numpy de un solo elemento. Puedes usar `[0]` para obtener ese valor en vez del array.
- Puedes usar interpolación cúbica en vez de lineal.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba, ¿un millón de gracias @abulafia!